# Importing eBay API XML into Excel

Tags: xml, vba, excel, ebay-api

I am currently using a short bit of XML to import data from the eBay API. My output works great on the API Explorer--but I cannot get it into Excel (XML below).

This is the XML that works on API Explorer, that I am trying to extract:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<GetOrdersRequest xmlns="urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents">
<!-- Call-specific Input Fields -->
<IncludeFinalValueFee>true</IncludeFinalValueFee>
<NumberOfDays>30</NumberOfDays>
<OrderRole>Seller</OrderRole>
<OrderStatus>Completed</OrderStatus>
<SortingOrder>Ascending</SortingOrder>
<!-- Standard Input Fields -->
<DetailLevel>ReturnSummary</DetailLevel>
<!-- ... more DetailLevel values allowed here ... -->
<ErrorLanguage>en_US</ErrorLanguage>
<MessageID>string</MessageID>
<!-- ... more OutputSelector values allowed here ... -->
<WarningLevel>Low</WarningLevel>
</GetOrdersRequest>
```

Does anyone have any suggestions or recommendations for a better method (or a fix for the current) to get this data out of the eBay API and into Excel?

The method I am currently using is below. The code runs... But returns nothing. I am pretty inexperienced with VBA (I typically use the record macro function...) but even getting some logging on the below to see what is going on would be helpful!

```
Sub GetSellerTransactions() 
Set objHTTP = CreateObject("WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1")
URL = "https://api.ebay.com/ws/api.dll"
objHTTP.Open "POST", URL, False
objHTTP.setRequestHeader "X-EBAY-API-DEV-NAME", "________"
objHTTP.setRequestHeader "X-EBAY-API-CERT-NAME", "________"
objHTTP.setRequestHeader "X-EBAY-API-APP-NAME", "________"
objHTTP.setRequestHeader "X-EBAY-API-CALL-NAME", "GetSellerTransactions"
objHTTP.setRequestHeader "X-EBAY-API-SITEID", "0"
objHTTP.setRequestHeader "X-EBAY-API-REQUEST-Encoding", "XML"
objHTTP.setRequestHeader "X-EBAY-API-COMPATIBILITY-LEVEL", "967"

objHTTP.send (body)

Set objXML = New MSXML2.DOMDocument
objXML.LoadXML (objHTTP.ResponseText)

Dim xItemList As IXMLDOMNodeList
Set xItemList = objXML.SelectNodes("//Item")

Row = 1

Dim xItem As IXMLDOMNode
Dim copy As Worksheet

For Each xItem In xItemList
Cells(Row, 1) = xItem.SelectNodes("//Buyer/UserID").Item(0).Text
Cells(Row, 2) = xItem.SelectNodes("//Buyer/Name").Item(0).Text
Cells(Row, 3) = xItem.SelectNodes("///Buyer/Phone").Item(0).Text
Cells(Row, 4) = xItem.SelectNodes("//Buyer/Email").Item(0).Text
Row = Row + 1
Next

Set objHTTP = Nothing
Set objXML = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: Post your code please and highlight what line of code is breaking.

Comment: the two examples that you mentioned are old. it is very likely that the eBay API has changed.

Comment: what is the API Explorer that you have mentioned?

Comment: Ah, does the given Xml represent a request?

Comment: The API explorer can be found here: https://developer.ebay.com/my/api_test_tool?index=0 . I will update the original code with the VBA code that I am working with right now.

Comment: @SMeaden I've updated the above code... This runs without breaking, but also does not return  any results. Adding 'debug.print' and looking into the immediate window doesn't seem to do anything either... Even getting logging to output something would be helpful. :) Haha.